# How to capture a key event and pass down to another class in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, mouselistener

I have a `JFrame` as my main class and made it focusable, given it a `MouseListener` and added some `JPanels`.

In the `JPanels` I have `Environment` classes that display images. Each `JPanel` only covers a part of the `JFrame`, and the `Environments` likewise cover a part of their parent `JPanel`.

I need to know how to properly capture `MouseEvent`s and pass them down through the chain to the correct `Environment` so they can be dealt with properly and update the corresponding image associated with that area

Are there methods built into the `JFrame` and `JPanel` that can at least get me as deep as the `JPanel`s or would I have to implement them myself?

I don't want to have to implement handlers for all the different `MouseEvents`, just pass the object down so that it can be handled at the lowest level.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "pass something to a class". Maybe you meant an object?

Comment: How do you know which panel is the right panel?  How do you make the determination.  *"Any suggestions would be appreciated"* - Don't use `KeyListener`, use the key bindings API instead anyway. [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: What class does `Environment` extend? I suggest you choose a more descriptive name for that class; it's difficult to know its purpose based on the name `Environment`.

Comment: Ya they would be objects, but Class objects specifically since everything is an object in java. Oh and sorry, i meant MouseKeyEvent
Environment doesn't extend any existing class at present. Each JPanel and each Environment would cover a set area so that there isn't any overlap. So the choice would be made based on the Point that the MouseKeyEvent was made at

Comment: Ahhh, there is no such thing as `MouseKeyEvent`...

Comment: Correction: `MouseEvent`

Comment: `MouseEvent`s are contextual to the component that generated them.  Assuming you're following some kind of OO principle, you could just create a custom panel which had it's own `MouseListener` and the functionality it needed to respond to those events.  You would simply then create what ever number of instance of this panel you needed...

Comment: Can you have multiple focusable components that will all capture `MouseEvents`?

Comment: Components don't need to be focusable to capture `MouseEvent`s, `JPanel` is not focusable by default it captures mouse events perfectly well.  Focus is related to "keyboard" focus (where key events go), not `MouseEvent`s, in fact, you can click a non-focusable component and not affect keyboard focus

Comment: After skimming the problem description my suggestion would be to read a little bit about Composite design pattern. Maybe you'll find some inspiration there :P